# Making specific method non transactional in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring application which is based on Spring Batch. By default spring batch introduces transaction for its steps (i.e. at reader,writer and processor) . There are certain stages where I don't really need transaction to be enabled. Because transaction is enabled unnecessary for these methods its giving me some runtime errors as I am making call to two different databases in one method.

Is there any annotation which spring provides to DISABLE transaction for a specific set of methods ?

OR is there anything available in spring batch which can allow me to get rid of transaction either completely or declarative

I am even open to the solution which can disable transaction globally.
Any link , paper will greatly be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Samir

Answer (score 3):

Spring Batch is inherently transactional.  Even if your datasources are not transactional, the semantics of the JobRepository require it.  The closest you can get with Spring Batch and not being transactional is using the ResourcelessTransactionManager.  This transaction manager is essentially a no-op transaction manager that just keeps track of if an operation is within the scope of a transaction or not.